# How to use the pdp in R to compute 3d partial dependence plots?

Tags: r, model, 3d

I have a Random forest model in R similar to this:

```
library("randomForest")
library("caret")
library("pdp")
data("cars")
my_data<-cars[1:5]
my_rf <- randomForest( Price ~ ., data=my_data)
price_mil<- partial(my_rf, pred.var = c("Price", "Mileage"))
plotPartial(price_mil, levelplot = FALSE, zlab = "Price", colorkey = TRUE)
```

However, I would like to have some 3d partial dependence plots, including the values of parameters on the axis. How can I do this with `pdp`?

Comment: Which cars dataset do you mean in your example ? The cars dataset from the standard datasets package is has no Price.

Comment: @SteffenMoritz, thank you for the notice. The car data are available in caret package. Just edited my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, In your example you used "price" in the `partial()` function. This does not make sense to me, as you essentially just plot a 2d partial dependence plot that way. I changed that in my example code below.

However, to get the requested partial plots you can use

```
plotPartial(price_mil, zlab = "Price", levelplot = F, scale = list(arrows = F))
```

If you want to have more control, I would advise to use the underlying functions of the package to construct your formula and wireframe object and then call `wireframe()` with `scale=list(arrows = F)` to add the values to the axes.

```
library("randomForest")
library("caret")
library("pdp")
data("cars")
my_data <- cars[1:5]
my_rf <- randomForest( Price ~ ., data=my_data)

object <- pdp::partial(my_rf, pred.var = c("Cylinder", "Mileage"))

form <- stats::as.formula(paste("yhat ~", paste(names(object)[1L:2L], 
                                                collapse = "*")))

wireframe(form, data = object, drape =T, zlab = "Price", scale = list(arrows = F))
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you @pookpash! It does works for my data. However, just a question, is there a way to remove the outer frame?

Comment: Yes, by specifying the parameter settings of either `wireframe()` or `plotPartial()` (in which case it gets passed to wireframe).
Use `par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))`.

Comment: Thx @pookpash. I am trying to produce 3D plots with color of yhat but my partial plot just doesn't scale the palette. My values go from 95 from 150, however, the entire legend is of one color. Do you think I can manage the color palette easily with the pdp package?

Comment: @FrsLry This is a bit hard to figure out without a reproducible example. If you provide one I will gladly take a look.
If you use my example code (the one above which calls `wireframe()`) do you get a figure with a color gradient?

Answer (score 3):

## Interactive 3D Partial Dependence Plot with plotly

```
# Random seed to reproduce the results
set.seed(1)

# Create artificial data for a binary classification problem 
y <- factor(sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = TRUE), levels = c("0", "1"))
d <- data.frame(y = y, x1 = rnorm(100), x2 = rnorm(100), x3 = rnorm(100))

# Build a random forest model
library(randomForest)
rf1 <- randomForest::randomForest(y ~., n.trees = 100, mtry = 2, data = d)

###### Bivariate partial dependency plots ######
# Step 1: compute the partial dependence values
# given two variables using the pdp library
library(pdp)
pd <- rf1 %>% partial(pred.var = c("x1", "x2"), n.trees = 100)

# Step 2: construct the plot using the plotly library 
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = pd$x1, y = pd$x2, z = pd$yhat, type = 'mesh3d')

# Step 3: add labels to the plot
p <- p %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "x1"),
                           yaxis = list(title = "x2"),
                           zaxis = list(title = "Partial Dependence")))

# Step 4: show the plot 
show(p)
```

[image]

## Interactive Contour Plot (i.e. flattened 2-variable PDP) with a color scale for the partial dependence values using plotly

```
###### Bivariate PDPs with colored scale ######
# Interpolate the partial dependence values 
dens <- akima::interp(x = pd$x1, y = pd$x2, z = pd$yhat)

# Flattened contour partial dependence plot for 2 variables
p2 <- plot_ly(x = dens$x,
          y = dens$y, 
          z = dens$z, 
          colors = c("blue", "grey", "red"),
          type = "contour")

# Add axis labels for 2D plots
p2 <- p2 %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = "x1"), yaxis = list(title = "x2"))
# Show the plot
show(p2)
```

[image]

## Interactive 3D Partial Dependence Plot with a color scale for the partial dependence values using plotly

```
###### Interactive 3D partial dependence plot with coloring scale ######

# Interpolate the partial dependence values
dens <- akima::interp(x = pd$x1, y = pd$x2, z = pd$yhat)

# 3D partial dependence plot with a coloring scale
p3 <- plot_ly(x = dens$x, 
          y = dens$y, 
          z = dens$z,
          colors = c("blue", "grey", "red"),
          type = "surface")
# Add axis labels for 3D plots
p3 <- p3 %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "x1"),
                             yaxis = list(title = "x2"),
                             zaxis = list(title = "Partial Dependence")))
# Show the plot
show(p3)
```

[image]